# Prevent disappearing of default text in textarea on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a textbox for order notes on the checkout page in which i have set the delivery schedule through code (PHP).

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

When the user clicks on the control the default text disappears. I want the text editing to be disabled and keep the scrolling intact.

Comment: Can you show us the code snippet here? I'm guessing you are talking about the placeholder text of the input text field. But looking at the code will help provide a more concise answer.

Comment: Its a long piece of code.

Comment: You can select the relevant pieces of it and paste them in blocks. At the very least, we will need to see the <input> or <textarea> that you are referring to as the textbox.

Comment: readonly and set text on value, or inside <textarea>**here**</textarea>

Answer (score 0):

Example of editable text:

```
<textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea>
```

Non interactable text:

```
<textarea disabled>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea>
```

placeholder (initial text disappearing on focus):

```
<textarea placeholder="Edit me..."></textarea>
```

all together (placeholder is useless here.. just showing that you can use multiple attributes):

```
<textarea placeholder="Edit me..." disabled>Lorem ipsum</textarea>
```

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/d5qv15oy/)